# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in Html button

Tags: javascript, html

I create a button dynamically through javascript.
When I click on it I get the mentioned error.

The button is created like this:

```
var button = document.createElement("Button");
            button.setAttribute("onclick", "FollowUser('" + name + "')");
            button.setAttribute("id", "FollowUserButton");
```

When debugging it, I've tried to figure out what goes wrong when I create it. It seems to be in the part where I make the onclick event. Nothing seems odd when I set the id.

This output is returned:

> button {disabled: false, form: null, formAction: "https://localhost:44398/Home/UserProfile?name=Test", …}

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute`, and don't use `onclick` event handler attributes. Just install an event listener with a closure: `button.onclick = function(event) { FollowUser(name); };`

Comment: use `button.addEventListener("click", e => FollowUser(name))`

Comment: That solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing my solution by presuming few things here. Please make sure to make the suitable changes in your code. The below code snippet will provide a base to the answer you want.

```js
let name = "foo";

var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var text = document.createTextNode("Click me");
button.appendChild(text);

button.setAttribute("onclick", `FollowUser('${name}')`);
button.setAttribute("id", "FollowUserButton");

// Append this button to a node. For instance, append it to the body.
document.body.appendChild(button);

// Function added for testing onclick event.
function FollowUser(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

I'm using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here to make the code more readable and less chaotic.